# python fuzzy reduce() has no initial value

Tags: python

I am trying a program to find the average fuzzy ratio of the word *good* within the lines of all text files in a directory and I am getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/hukj.py", line 28, in <module>
    my_sum, my_len = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]), ((good_ratio(i), 1) for i in my_file))
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

for the following program:

```
import os
path = r'C:\Python27' 
data = {}
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def good_ratio(a):
   return fuzz.ratio(a, 'good')

for dir_entry in os.listdir(path):
        dir_entry_path = os.path.join(path, dir_entry)
        if os.path.isfile(dir_entry_path):
            with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
               my_sum, my_len = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]), ((good_ratio(i), 1) for i in my_file))
               print(my_sum/my_len)
```

What might cause this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the `((good_ratio(i), 1) for i in my_file)` generator expression did not produce any values:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: None, ())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

This only would happen if your `dir_entry_path` file was empty; e.g. no lines were being produced at all.

You could simply catch the exception and move on to the next file:

```
with open(dir_entry_path, 'r') as my_file:
   try:
       my_sum, my_len = reduce(lambda a, b: (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]), ((good_ratio(i), 1) for i in my_file))
   except TypeError:
       # file empty, move to next file
       continue
   print(my_sum/my_len)
```